# How to find files containing empty strings

Tags: bash

One of our suppliers has a buggy shop floor system (long story short). While they fix whatever is wrong on their end, I need to segregate files they send: they are not empty but have a long empty string. Typically a good file will look like this in vi

```
    <insert_list><test_event_insert  endTime="2012-09-10T05:28:45" startTime="2012-09-10T05:27:41" operator="8176967"><process_step name="FVT" revision="NO DATA"></process_step><location1 name="CT" type="REGION"><location2 name="ONTREP1" type="TESTER"><location3 name="LineA" type="LINE"></location3></location2></location1><unit ...
"CT~DCA~FVT~8176967~ONTREP1~4~P~1100~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1033A4675~20120910~052846.XML" [noeol][dos] 3L, 2170C
```

a bad file will look this:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...

"CT~DCA~FVT~8176967~ONTREP1~2~P~1100~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1045B6072~20120904~043209.XML" [noeol] 1L, 2170C
```

The caret/at sign combo is VI's interpretation of that string, I guess but it is in fact an empty string. Using `-z` seems to work on one single file

```
X=CT~DCA~FVT~8176967~ONTREP1~2~P~1100~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1045B6072~20120904~043209.XML
if [ ! -z $X ] 
then 
echo "$X empty"
else 
echo "$X not empty"
fi
    CT~DCA~FVT~8176967~ONTREP1~2~P~1100~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1045B6072~20120904~043209.XML empty
```

But the same code is telling me that all 900 files on my EMC mass filer are empty. Which is not true.

```
export OUT=/path/to/device
declare -a myArray
for f in "$OUT"/*ONTREP1*; do myArray+=( "${f#$OUT/}" ); done
for i in "${myArray[@]}"; do  if [ ! -z $i ] ; then echo "$i empty"; else echo "$i not empty"; fi; done
```

NB: Pattern "*ONTREP1*" is to narrow down the faulty files to one shop floor computer name.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `if grep '\x00' filename`.  Not all grep's support \x00 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that `test -z string` tests whether a string is empty (as opposed to `test -s file` which tests whether a file is empty.) Furthermore the ^@ in vim are an indication of NUL bytes--bytes with the value 0. It looks like these are binary data files or maybe corrupted, but certainly not empty. An empty file in vim displays as all tildes (~) in the leftmost column :-)

Try running the `file filename` command on the good and bad files; the latter probably says "data" due to the NUL bytes.

Comment: Filtering on file -b ${filename} = "data" took care of it. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.